# Using Vaadin Grid with AngularJs (1.6) data layer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vaadin8

I have an application written in AngularJS and would like to use Vaadin grid to display some data coming from an angular controller.

Something like this:

controller.js:

```
this.$onInit = () => {
    this.items: [{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}, {name: 'baz'}]
}
```

template.html:

```
<vaadin-grid items="$ctrl.items">
    <vaadin-grid-column>
        <template class="header">Name</template>
        <template>[[item.name]]</template>
    </vaadin-grid-column>
</vaadin-grid>
```

But AngularJS doesn't render content inside a template tag.

Is there anyway to make this work?